# Шейдер отражает свет только со стороны нормали

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Есть вот такой шейдер

```
Shader "Diffuse " {
Properties {
_Color("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}

}
SubShader {
Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
LOD 150
Cull Off

CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert noforwardadd

sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;

struct Input {
float2 uv_MainTex;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
o.Albedo = c.rgb * _Color;
o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG
}

Fallback "Mobile/VertexLit"
}
```

Если использовать его на материале объекта, то объект освещается только со стороны нормали, а противоположная сторона остаётся неосвещённой, даже если направить свет прямо на неё. Что туда добавить, чтобы свет отображался на обратной нормали стороне тоже? Это работает на шейдере  `Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Leaves`, однако шейдер этот очень тяжёлый и ссылается на другой, а тот в свою очередь -еще на другой. Ну и много лишнего там. Шейдер сверху - очень лёгкий и хотелось бы добавить что то минимальное, просто чтобы освещалось две стороны - нормаль и противоположная нормали.

Наглядный пример ниже. Освещение работает на фронтальную сторону и не работает на внутреннюю. Цианом выделены нормали
[image: Наглядный пример. Цианом выделены нормали]

Comment: Вам правильно сказали в ответе JediMan - у вас неверное настроены нормали, с "тыльной" стороны меши они направлены вовнутрь меши.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, нужно сделать нормали двухсторонними в 3D редакторе, где были созданы модели (или в любом 3D редакторе, куда можно импортировать модель). Так у вас нормали односторонние, соответственно только "главная" сторона будет отрисовывать все эффекты.

Comment: А что такое "двусторонние нормали"? Тут самые обычные нормали не везде верно стоят.

Comment: @JediMan
Это один из способов, но он не подразумевает программирования. Нужно чтобы именно текущие модели освещались с обоих сторон.

Comment: @Dmitrii, у вас кривые модели, вам правильно указали, что нужно это исправить. Варианта 2 - сам 3д редактор и `Mesh.RecalculateNormals` с `Mesh.RecalculateTangents`. Причем второй способ не будет работать, если у вас неправильно настроено "направление" полигонов.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я понимаю, что это один из способов решения проблемы, и, возможно, самый правильный. Но меня интересует именно решение через шейдер, т.к. я вижу что шейдер Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Leaves поддерживает освещение с обоих сторон, и хочу добавить именно эту часть кода из него

Comment: @Dmitrii вы вообще понимаете, что такое нормали? Вы не сможете без нормальных нормалей получить правильное освещение объекта, как бы вы не старались.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker

Погодите, но другой шейдер это успешно делает. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Dmitrii ну вы приведите пример, я не могу наугад вам ответить на вопрос

Comment: @RiotBr3aker
Пример - шейдер `Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Leaves` при точно такой же ситуации, как выше на скриншоте, принимает освещение и со стороны нормалей и со стороны где их нет.

Comment: @Dmitrii, вы использовали абсолютно неподходящий для обычных мешей шейдер, ещё и не настроили его для работы с оклюдией. И после этого вы утверждаете, что с вашей мешей все нормально? Используйте обычный стандартный шейдеры и получите ту же проблему. Я вам уже давно объяснил проблему, вы наотрез отказываетесь в нее верить и пытаетесь мне шейдером для листвы что-то доказать. Не хотите верить в проблему - не верьте, я вам ничего доказывать не собираюсь и уже порядком устал из раза в аз твердить одно и то же.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker
Спасибо! Да, я понимаю что обычные шейдеры освещают объект, исходя из его нормалей. И я понимаю, что если я возьму стандартный шейдер, я получу тот же результат. Я понимаю, что шейдер листьев не подходит под обычные меши и создан не для них - я и спрашиваю, что именно, какой кусок кода в шейдере `Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Leaves` позволяет сделать это? Я хочу использовать его в своем шейдере, или хотя бы разобратся, как работает освещение стороны меша без нормалей.

Comment: @Dmitrii, один вопрос: зачем? Какой смысл делать очень сложное решение, если проще просто пересчитать нормали и все заработает? Вы спросил, как максимально просто решить проблему и не добавлять много кода в ваш шейдер, перенести решение из `Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion Leaves` не получится - это априори не "простой" шейдер. Так или иначе, я свое видение решения высказал, если вы хотите сделать иначе - ваше право. Если вы так хотите - сами с ознакомьтесь этим шейдером, у меня на это нет ни времени, ни желания.